# My father provided me with money so that I could/was able to go to those swimming lessons - differences in meaning

Tags: meaning, modal-verbs, could-modal

**Example 1**

> My father provided me with money so that I **could** go to those swimming lessons.

**Example 2**

> My father provided me with money so that I **was able to** go to those swimming lessons.

**Example 3**

> My father provided me with money so that I **went** to those swimming lessons.

Example 3 basically means that I did go to the swimming lessons.

However, what is the difference between "could" and "was able to" here?

Does "could" mean that I got the ability to go to the swimming lessons but I did not necessarily do it?

Does "was able to" mean that I actually did go to the lessons?

Can Example 1 have the same meaning as Example 3?

Comment: Example #2 is "peculiar". I can only understand it as meaning that speaker's father gave him money for some other reason (or no particular reason; sometimes that's just what generous fathers do). And ***as an [unforeseen, but not necessarily unwanted] consequence** of having been given that money, speaker was able to pay for swimming lessons*. Example #3 is even more strange, but it kinda suggests to me that speaker ***didn't want*** swimming lessons (the money was a "bribe" to force him to take them).

Comment: If you wanted to convey the (incredibly unlikely) sense that speaker *didn't* have the lessons even though that's why the father gave him the money in the first place, you'd need to use a lot more words.

Comment: None of the versions sounds natural. If Father paid for the lessons, you would either say that or say _My father provided me with the money to go for swimming lessons_.

Comment: I don't really see the point of the bounty here. By far the biggest "difference" between example #1 and the other two is that #2 and #3 aren't at all likely to be used by a native speaker in the first place. What use is it to know what something *would* mean, if the only likely source is a non-native speaker anyway?

Comment: I would not say provided here. I would use "gave me the money" And here *could* and  *was able* to mean the same thing. They are not the same as went. So that I went is merely a consequence. Conversation context: But, Jean, My father gave me the money so I **was able/could** to go to those swimming lessons. The point is they are all grammatical and could be used in certain situations.

Comment: https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/english-usage/what-is-the-difference-between-can-could-and-be-able-to It's all there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My natural reading of the sentence differs from this. I interpret "so" as "for the purpose of." This makes Example 2 read like: "My father provided me with money for the purpose of being able to go to those swimming lessons."

Comment: @KateBunting Is your example British English, by any chance?

Comment: @BigMistake - Yes. My profile makes it clear that I'm British. Does that make a difference, in your view?

Comment: @BigMistake: I think that kinda proves my point. The fact that we have different ideas about what example #2 *would* mean (if used by a native Anglophone, which is unlikely) strongly implies that it's *not* a "natural" usage. If it *was* natural phrasing, we'd probably both agree on the same meaning without giving it a thought. But because it (probably) *didn't / doesn't* come from a native Anglophone, we're really just making things up when we try to say what it "would" mean.

Comment: @KateBunting Ah, I see that now. I don't hear people say "to go for" in that context, so I was wondering. (I am sure you are correct--just wanted to figure out why I haven't heard that phrase.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My father provided me with money so that I could go to those swimming
> lessons.

Meaning: you father provided you with money for the purpose of going to those swimming lessons. The swimming lessons probably happened in the past, but not necessarily.

> My father provided me with money so that I was able to go to those
> swimming lessons.

Meaning: you father provided you with money to make it possible for you to go to those swimming lessons. (This has almost the same meaning as the previous example. The swimming lessons must have happened in the past if they happened.)

> My father provided me with money so that I went to those swimming
> lessons.

This is wrong. Here is the corrected version:

> My father provided me with money, so I went to those swimming
> lessons.

This means you've already gone to the swimming lessons, because you got the money. This is different from Example 1 in the sense that Example 1's swimming lessons could happen in the future.

> However, what is the difference between "could" and "was able to"
> here?

Almost nothing. The interpreted meaning is the same.

> Does "could" mean that I got the ability to go to the swimming lessons but I > did not necessarily do it?

Yes, but with no other context, most people would guess that you did go to the swimming lessons, though it is possible that you did not.

> Does "was able to" mean that I actually did go to the lessons?

No. It means it was possible to. This is the same meaning as above. If anything, this has more of connotation that maybe you didn't go.

Can Example 1 have the same meaning as Example 3?
The corrected version of Example 3 has almost the same meaning as Example 1, except in Example 1, it is still possible that you didn't or won't attend (or even didn't attend quite yet, but will attend). However, if you said this with no context and meant that you didn't really attend, it would be seen as a technicality by most speakers, and possibly as deceitful without clarifying that you did not attend.